# How to resolve the sonarqube static code analysis error "Explicitly define the missing copy constructor, move constructor .." in C++

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I am getting the below sonarqube static code analysis error:

**Explicitly define the missing copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator and move assignment operator so that they will not be implicitly provided.**

I am getting the above message at the below Destructor declaration in the header file:

```
~CCPSDataManager();
```

And also in my .cpp file, there is definition for this Destructor ~CCPSDataManager().

Here do I need to follow the rule of 5 by providing the Destructor, copy constructor and the copy-assignment operator, move constructor and the move-assignment operator? Or is there any other approach?

And also If I define the copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, move constructor and the move-assignment operator we are writing many lines of code without using those. Is this a correct approach?

Please suggest and give me some insight on how to proceed?

Comment: Do the class have members that could be replaced by RAII constructs? Does it do any kind of dynamic allocation or resource acquisition? What is the destructor doing? Do you really need the destructor?

Comment: We declared a resource using smart pointer like : static shared_ptr<CSDKDataManager>    m_ActiveInstance;    And then in the destructor, we are setting it as "NULL"    CCPSDataManager :: ~CCPSDataManager()
{
    m_ActiveInstance = NULL;
}   I think we can delete the line  m_ActiveInstance = NULL; from the destructor as the resource is of type shared_ptr.

And also we can remove the destructor definition, declaration and can follow the rule of zero. Please suggest.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly set smart pointers to be null pointers, once the smart pointer object goes out of scope it will do the right thing. Which means you can follow the rule of *zero* instead, and remove your destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here do I need to follow the rule of 5 by providing the Destructor, copy constructor and the copy-assignment operator, move constructor and the move-assignment operator?

Depends on what you do in the destructor.

In most cases, if you need a destructor, then you need to follow rule of 5 because in most cases the implicitly generated ones do the wrong thing. Not always, but in most cases. The analyser that you use suggests to follow the rule of 5 because of the assumption that it may be necessary.

> Or is there any other approach?

If there is no need for the custom destructor, then follow the rule of 0 instead: Don't define a custom destructor.

> And also If I define the copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, move constructor and the move-assignment operator we are writing many lines of code without using those.

If you don't use them, then simplest solution is to define them deleted.

Comment: Thank you @eerorika for your explanation: My understanding from your explanation is, Sonarqube is giving the error because the compiler is implicitly looking for the definition of at least one of the remaining four functions in the rule of 5 scenario,

So if i am not sure which function the compiler is implicitly trying to invoke then,

can i make all the remaining four operations as = delete

And once I compiled, based on the error/warning can i define the function which is required?